# Segmentation fail freeing a pointer

Tags: c

There two "free(t)" on my function. When I call the function and goes to the first free(t) everything works fine, then the function self evokes itself and then, in the free(t) of the bottom of the code, occurs segmentation fail. Why this happens? And why the first "free(t)" doesnt result in segmentation fail and the secund result? Thanks

```
char c[50];
int b, j=0, d=0, e=0;
PLAYER *pt1;
MANAGER *pt2;

t=malloc(24*sizeof(TEAM));
tfile=fopen("team.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(tfile, "%d %s %d %d %d%c", &t[j].tablep, t[j].initials, &t[j].birth.day, &t[j].birth.month, &t[j].birth.year)!=EOF){   
    fgets(t[j].name, 50, tfile);
    t[j].name[strlen(t[j].name)-1]='\0';        
    j++;
}
fclose(tfile);
t[j].name[0]=0; 
j=0;
while(t[j].name[0]!=0){
    printf("\t%i. %s\n", j+1, t[j].name);
    j++;
}
do{
printf("What is the team of the player:"); 
scanf(" %c", &b); 
b=b-48;
if(b<1 || b>j+1){
    printf("Invalid choice. Try again.\n");
    teamlists(a);
}       
}while(b<1 || b>j);
j=0;
if(a==2){

}
else{   //(a==3)
    pt2=malloc(sizeof(MANAGER));
    memcpy(pt2, m, sizeof(*pt2));
    m=malloc(24*sizeof(MANAGER));
    reader(3);
    while(m[j].name[0]!=0){
        if(strcmp(m[j].team, t[b-1].name)==0){
            do{
                printf("This team already have a manager.\nEnter: \t1. to choose another team \t2. to return to menu ");
                scanf(" %c", &e);
                e=e-48;
                if(e!=1 && e!=2)
                    printf("Invalid choice. Try again.\n"); 
                if(e==1 || e==2){
                    free(t);
                    free(m);                        
                }
                if(e==1){
                    m=malloc(sizeof(MANAGER));
                    memcpy(m, pt2, sizeof(*m));
                    teamlists(a);                           
                }
                if(e==2){
                    main();
                    free(pt2);
                }           
            }while(e!=1 && e!=2);   
        }
        j++;            
    }
    free(m);
    memcpy(m, pt2, sizeof(*m));
    strcpy(m->team, t[b-1].name);   
    free(t);
    free(pt);   
}
```

}

Comment: You are already `free`ing `t` once in your code. Why are you trying to `free` it again? What do you expect to protect you from double `free`ing `t`?

Comment: TEAM is a global struct. When I free t in one of the times I necesseraly evoke function again or evoke main, so I wont ever free t two times, I think

Comment: Add a printf before you free the memory to see what the memory address is.  Then you could verify that you really are calling free for the same memory twice.  You could also add a similar printf after the mallocs to see the memory address of what is being allocated.

Comment: Sanitize your loops.

Comment: In case "a==3", you are doing `memcpy(pt2, m, sizeof(*pt2));` but `m` is _not_ allocated yet. `m=malloc(24*sizeof(MANAGER));` is on the _next_ line, so you're copying from an _uninitialized_ `m`, which is _bad_ and could segfault. I'd start fixing these sorts of bugs as they can easily contribute to your problem. That is, sometimes `free` doesn't know if it's getting a double free or the internal structs used by `malloc` et. al. get corrupted by overwriting with haywire pointers (e.g. like you have in the above).

Comment: m is already allocated in the function where i call this function

Comment: @Fezudo: What "function" are you talking about? What exactly do you "evoke again"? Also, whatever you are evoking, you will eventually return back from it and do `free(t)` the second time.

Comment: If `m` is _already_ allocated in another function, doing the `m=malloc(24*sizeof(MANAGER));` as I mentioned above, _trashes_ the previous value, creating a memory leak. So, this is _still_ a bug [of a different sort] that needs to be fixed. Either of these could easily cause your original issue.

Answer (score 2):

[**7.22.3.3 The free function**, paragraph 2 of the C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2) states:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or **if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined**.

You're invoking undefined behavior by freeing the same pointer twice.

Your symptom is a fatal segmentation violation that kills your program.

Comment: But when I do a free I evoke the function again, and at the top of the function I malloc t. Then the function dont go the first free(t), it goes to the free at the bottom of the code. I have debugged the program and follow is steps and there is never a free after a free, only a malloc, a free, a malloc and a free

Comment: @Fezudo If you overrun a buffer that's created by a call to `malloc()` (or any similar function), you also invoke undefined behavior.  One symptom of corrupting memory like that is a later call to `malloc()` or `free()` will fail because the buffer overwrite destroys some of the internal data used by the library to keep track of allocated memory.